# what are the downsides of splitting /proc/pid/stat by whitespace?

Tags: linux, proc

What are the downsides of splitting `/proc/pid/stat` on Linux by whitespace? For example using `bash` one can access the third column via

```
$ cat /proc/$$/stat
14198 (bash) S 14195 14198 14198 34816 ...
$ x=($(< /proc/$$/stat)); echo ${x[2]}
S
$
```

and all seems well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to even think about it, why not just read `/proc/$pid/status` instead. It gives the same information on nicely labeled lines, *and* escapes newlines and backslashes that appear in the process name:

```
$ perl -e '$0="foo\nbar\n"; system "head -3 /proc/$$/status";'
Name:   foo\nbar\n
Umask:  0022
State:  S (sleeping)
```

Comment: that's probably easier for `perl` or such but likely more difficult for C to deal with ( https://github.com/Microsoft/ProcDump-for-Linux/issues/8 )

Comment: @thrig, eh, that code there reads `/proc/$pid/stat`, not `status`. So no wonder it has trouble. Reading a single-datum-per-line file in C is just a loop over `fgets()` and `strcmp` (for the headers). Though I do think I'll go to sleep now instead of coding the un-escaping.

Answer (score 5):

The chief problem is that the space character (`0x20`) is used both for the delimiter between records and may also appear within a record; should a local user be able to set the process name

```
$ perl -e '$0="like this"; sleep 999' &
[1] 14343
$
```

then the parse splitting by whitespace will fail

```
$ x=($(< /proc/14343/stat)); echo ${x[2]}
this)
$
```

as the command name contains a space.

```
$ cat /proc/14343/stat
14343 (like this) S 14198 14343 ...
$
```

How bad could this be? According to [`proc(5)`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) the "controlling terminal of the process" is interesting

```
          tty_nr %d   (7) The controlling terminal of the  process.   (The
                      minor  device number is contained in the combination
                      of bits 31 to 20 and 7 to 0; the major device number
                      is in bits 15 to 8.)
```

so if a process misuses the controlling terminal information parsed incorrectly from `/proc/pid/stat` because someone changed that information, well, you [may get a security vulnerability](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-1000367).

The parsing is additionally complicated by the fact that a `)` can be placed in the process name though there is a 15 character limit

```
$ perl -e '$0="lisp) a b c d e f g h i"; sleep 999' &
[4] 14440
$ cat /proc/14493/stat
14493 (lisp) a b c d e) S 14198 14493 14198 34816 ...
$
```

### Ideas to Parse this Wart of an Interface

Since the process name can vary somewhere between the empty string and 15 bytes of almost any contents

```
1234 () S ...
4321 (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) S ...
```

one idea would be to split on the first space to obtain the pid, then work backwards from the end of this string to find the first `)`; the stuff before the first `)` from the right should be the process name and to the left the regular fields. Unit tests for the code would be highly advisable...

Comment: It’s often better to parse one of the other files in `/proc/pid`, if all the information needed is in a single file, or race conditions aren’t an issue. (So if anyone thought of reading `/proc/pid/comm` to help with parsing `/proc/pid/stat`, no, it isn’t a good idea.)